# Naming a list after a variable

Tags: r

My database needs a certain input on the format:

```
list(symbol1=list(param1='value1', ...), symbol2=list(param2='value2', ...), ...)
```

As I don't need to pass any params, and will only need to look at one symbol at the time my call to the data base will look like this:

```
symbolList <- list("INSTR_SPACE::ID123456SWEDEN"=list())
```

(this works)

But here comes my problem.. I want to pass the string "INSTR_SPACE::ID123456SWEDEN" by variable when i create the list.

i.e

```
var = "INSTR_SPACE::ID123456SWEDEN" 
symbolList <- list(var=list())
```

This does not give me the desired result as it just declares var to a empty list within a list.
I have tried working with as.character and setNames but I cant get it to work...

What would be the R-way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: `names(symbolList) <- var`

Comment: Works! Thanks <3
`var = "INSTR_SPACE::ID123456SWEDEN"
symbolList <- list(list())
names(symbolList) <- var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not working because constructor of list `list()` works in the form of `list(tag = value())` and it auto-coerces `tag` to string hence `var` is considered as a string when you call it inside the constructor of parent list itself.

Correct way of doing this would be

1. create parent list first

   ```
   symbolList<-list()
   ```
2. insert child elements dynamically and yes these elements can be a list too.

   ```
   var<-"XYZ"
   symbolList[[var]]<-list()

   > symbolList
   $`INSTR_SPACE::ID123456SWEDEN`
   list()
   ```